# Flask debug=True does not work when going through uWSGI

Tags: python, wsgi, flask

I call `app.run(debug=True)` in my flask file.

and I have it deployed with uWSGI and nginx (I followed [these instructions](http://readncode.com/blog/Deploying-Flask-with-nginx-uWSGI-and-Supervisor/))

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w flask_file_name:app -H /path/to/virtual/env --chmod-socket 666
```

But when I get an error, I don't get any debug information in the browser or in the uWSGI log.

Any ideas?

flask_file_name.py:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, Response, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Can you post `flask_file_name.py`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [the Flask mailing list](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/10/19/debug-when-deploy-in-uwsgi/#7be089baf631971dfb73a5a7b79e2248) you cannot use Flask's debug option with `uWSGI`, because it's not to be used in a forking environment.

> You see 502 because flask/werkzeug do not send any data to the webserver, 
>   so nginx will returns a 502.
>
> You can emulate the debugger using --catch-exceptions option in uWSGI 
>   (but please do not do it in production)

So, the reason you're seeing 502s will be because of that. The fix would be to add `--catch-exceptions` to `uWSGI` on execution.

Comment: You are the man! It's still not formatted like it was without uWSGI, but I do get the error now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, but also see the comment by gonz, below. :)

Comment: Worked for me if I set debug mode in py file: `app.debug = True`.

Answer (score 35):

This question is old, but I'll post this for future reference...

If you want to get the werkzeug error page to work with uwsgi, try using werkzeug's `DebuggedApplication` middleware:

```
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, True)
```

That should do the trick but DO NOT FORGET to do this ONLY in development environments.

Comment: This worked for me, the other answers didn't. Thanks.

Comment: To make the debugger prompt work, you have to use a single worker in uwsgi (--workers 1, --threads 4)

Comment: It worked for me if only I I set debug mode: app.debug = True

Answer (score 25):

The problem is `uwsgi` does not call `app.run()`. It calls `app()`. So instead you can do this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Now if I have a syntax error, it redirects to the nginx static 50x.html error page. How can I get flask to handle that?

Comment: Worked for me if I set `catch-exceptions = true` in uwsgi.ini.

Answer (score 3):

For me it only worked after I combined the two answers above like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, True)

app.debug = True
```

Comment: Worked for me, this is the best solution for me.