# Flask + uwsgi + nginx + debug. 502 error instead of debugger page

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

Run Flask on server with uWsgi.

uWsgi config

```
<uwsgi>
    <socket>/tmp/flask.sock</socket>
    <pythonpath>/home/reweb/flask/</pythonpath>
    <module>publicist:app</module>
    <plugins>python27</plugins>
    <uid>reweb</uid>
   <touch-reload>/home/reweb/reload</touch-reload>
</uwsgi>
```

nginx config

```
upstream flask_serv {
    server unix:/tmp/flask.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some-domain.com;

    access_log /home/reweb/log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/reweb/log/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass flask_serv;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

But instead of debugger page nginx show me 502 error.
All Flask error traceback i can see in uwsgi error log.

**UPDATE**
Find old question [nginx + uwsgi + flask - disabling custom error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146210/nginx-uwsgi-flask-disabling-custom-error-pages) there is no answer

Comment: Have you tried this without upstream?

Comment: @JoeDoherty, yes, all the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask debug=True does not work when going through uWSGI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364854/flask-debug-true-does-not-work-when-going-through-uwsgi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460399/814470
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17839750/814470

Two answers from duplicated question

Answer (score 1):

[Flask debug=True does not work when going through uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364854/flask-debug-true-does-not-work-when-going-through-uwsgi)

may help.  Essentially, uwsgi is not intended for development environments where you want debugging info in the browser. It's a production server.

possibly adding in `app.debug = true` may help, after you have instantiated the Flask object, but otherwise, to get a proper debugger, use the flask internal server for development.